# How to cancel Rx Based Web Request in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, system.reactive

In my application i am using a Rx based web request for fetching the data from the server. Suppose if i want to cancel the request, what i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the extension method TakeUntil(someEvent), before Subscribe, where SomeEvent could be an Observable.FromEventPattern fired from button click event, for example.

Let us know,

regards,

Comment: i am using observable-subscription method, My requirement is that, i need to cancel the request, at the same time i need to enter the complete action. how i can achieve the same.l

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to cancel the subscription to an observable that is performing the web request then all you need to do is call `.Dispose()` on the disposable returned from the `.Subscribe(Action action)` method.

Comment: Yup i tried this; but the issue is that it is not entering in complete action. I added some code logic in my Complete action.