# How to dispose nested Rx web request calls in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, system.reactive

In my application i am using chain of of web request call for fetching data from the net. Ie from the result of one request i will send other request and so on. But when i am disposing the web request, only the parent request is disposing. The two other request are still running. How i can cancel all these request in Rx

Comment: Please post your code. Using a simple `SelectMany` query can solve your problem in one line, but it is hard to explain how it would apply to your situation without referencing your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your subscription to terminate everything, you either cannot break the monad or you need to make sure that you work into the `IDisposable` model.

To keep the monad (ie. stick with IObservables):

```
var subscription = initialRequest.GetObservableResponse()
    .SelectMany(initialResponse =>
    {
        // Feel free to use ForkJoin or Zip (intead of Merge) to 
        // end up with a single value
        return secondRequest.GetObservableResponse()
            .Merge(thirdRequest.GetObservableResponse());
    })
    .Subscribe(subsequentResponses => { });
```

To make use of the `IDisposable` model:

```
var subscription = initialRequest.GetObservableResponse()
    .SelectMany(initialResponse =>
    {
        return Observable.CreateWithDisposable(observer =>
        {
            var secondSubscription = new SerialDisposable();
            var thirdSubscription = new SerialDisposable();

            secondSubscription.Disposable = secondRequest.GetObservableResponse()
                .Subscribe(secondResponse =>
                {
                    // Be careful of race conditions here!

                    observer.OnNext(value);
                    observer.OnComplete();
                });

            thirdSubscription.Disposable = thirdRequest.GetObservableResponse()
                .Subscribe(thirdResponse =>
                {
                    // Be careful of race conditions here!
                });

            return new CompositeDisposable(secondSubscription, thirdSubscription);
        });
    })
    .Subscribe(subsequentResponses => { });
```

Answer (score 1):

One approah is by using TakeUntil extnsion method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990882/how-to-cancel-rx-based-web-request-in-windows-phone-7/9991251#9991251). In your case, the event that takes this method as parameter could be some event thrown by the parent request.

If you could show us some code we can face the problem more specifically.

regards,